# P10 to P8 in S-DES

Tags: encryption, reference-request, s-des

I am new to cryptography. During my learning I am facing a problem with S-DES. I am confused where `P10` to `P8` come from, and I’m confused about the processing of this algorithm. Does anyone have any good article/paper/reference which enables me to understand how to solve it easily?

I am reading following example but getting confuse..

**Example:**

```
P10 = { 3, 5, 2, 7, 4, 10, 1, 9, 8, 6}
P8 = { 6, 3, 7, 4, 8, 5, 10, 9}
K =     10100 00010
P10     10000 01100
LS-1    00001 11000  ->  P8  ->  K1 = 1010 0100
LS-2    00100 00011  ->  P8  ->  K2 = 0100 0011
```

Comment: See [SIMPLIFIED  DES](http://mercury.webster.edu/aleshunas/COSC%205130/G-SDES.pdf), William Stallings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

S-DES is a toy cipher intended for learning, defined by Edward F. Schaefer, *A Simplified Data Encryption Standard Algorithm*, in [Cryptologia Volume 20, Issue 1, 1996 (paywalled with free preview)](http://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/0161-119691884799). It has the same structure as [DES](http://csrc.nist.gov/publications/fips/fips46-3/fips46-3.pdf#page=13), and uses the same notations:

- bits vectors (such as key and data) are numbered starting from 1 "on the left"
- functions of bit vector giving bit vector, where each bit of the output vector is a fixed bit of the input vector, are expressed by a series of decimal numbers, giving, for each bit of the output, the index of the corresponding bit in the input.

`P10` and `P8` are such functions, which mimic PC1 and PC2 in DES. They are part of the definition of S-DES. `P10` is an entirely arbitrary permutation of 10 bits. `P8` is a selection of 8 bits out of 10.

`P10` transforms a 10-bit vector into a 10-bit vector, such that the j<sup>th</sup> bit of the output is at the index in the input given by the j<sup>th</sup> number in `3, 5, 2, 7, 4, 10, 1, 9, 8, 6`.
For example, the 2<sup>nd</sup> bit in the output is the 5<sup>th</sup> bit in the input, because the 2<sup>nd</sup> number in the above sequence of numbers is 5.

`P8` transforms a 10-bit vector into an 8-bit vector, such that the j<sup>th</sup> bit of the output is at the index in the input given by the j<sup>th</sup> number in `6, 3, 7, 4, 8, 5, 10, 9`.
For example, the 7<sup>th</sup> bit in the output is the 10<sup>th</sup> bit in the input, because the 7<sup>th</sup> number in the above sequence of numbers is 10.

---

The rest of the text in the question has the following meaning/rationale:

The key `K = 1010000010` of S-DES is a 10-bit vector. `K` is transformed using `P10`, yielding a 10-bit vector `CD0 = 1000001100`, which is split into two 5-bit vectors `C0 = 10000` and `D0 = 01100`.

In the first round,

- `C0` and `D0` each are [rotated on the left](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/25238/how-does-rotl-work/25239#25239) by one, yielding `C1 = 00001` and `D1 = 11000`.
- `C1`and `D1` are joined into `CD1 = 1100011000`.
- `CD1` is transformed using `P8`, yielding `K1 = 10100100`.

In the second round,

- `C1` and `D1` each are rotated on the left by two, yielding `C2 = 00100` and `D2 = 00011`.
- `C2`and `D2` are joined into `CD2 = 0010000011`.
- `CD2` is transformed using `P8`, yielding `K2 = 01000011`.

`K1` and `K2` are the round keys for the first two rounds, and are used as input of the round functions.

Answer (score -4):

P10 and P8 are standard transposition keys that just need to be learnt.
They are part of the S-DES standard.

Comment: One should not _learn_ P10 and P8, but understand how they are used. S-DES is not a standard; it's a toy cipher.